# Texts on coalescent theory/probability methods for DNA evolution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mathematical-biology, bioinformatics

I am starting a PhD on mitochondrial evolution modelling with a focus on probabilistic methods and coalescent theory. For this purpose, I am looking for

1. advanced textbooks on probability methods for DNA evolution/coalescent theory,
2. Recent-ish (past 10 years) review articles on these topics.
3. Any lecture notes on the topic from the same period.

These are the resources I already know about:

- [Coalescent Theory: An Introduction, John Wakeley (2009)](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Coalescent_Theory.html?id=x30RAgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
- [Probability Models for DNA Sequence Evolution, Rick Durrett (2013](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Probability_Models_for_DNA_Sequence_Evol/vIjSBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))
- [Some Mathematical Models From Population Genetics (published lecture notes), Alison Etheridge (2012)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-16632-7)
- [Stochastic Models in Mathematical Genetics (Online lectures notes), Simon Myers (2020)](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Emyers/mathgenteaching.html)

[Crosspost on mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842106/texts-on-coalescent-theory-probability-methods-for-dna-evolution)

Comment: It's possible that https://biology.stackexchange.com/ (a Stack Exchange site devoted to biology) would be a better place for this question.

Comment: It's right at the 10 year mark, but would "ReCombinatorics" by Dan Gusfield be relevant?

Comment: @JCK Indeed it does seem very relevant, and I was not aware of it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.